# Returning status from a worker class

Tags: c#

I have a service class and a worker class. The worker class does all the processing.

```
class WorkerClass
{
    public void ProcessWork(<params to the method>)
    {
        // Get the tasks from the DB.
        // Call a 3rd party web service to process each of the tasks.
    }
}
```

In my service class, I instantiate the worker class and call the method. The question is, how do I get the number of tasks processed in the service class?

I have thought of 3 options:

1. Expose an event from the worker class. Hook up an event handler in the service class.
2. Modify the signature of `ProcessWork` method so that it accepts a delegate:

   ```
   public void ProcessWork(object obj1, Action<int, int> actionProgressTracker)
   ```
3. Expose a property from the worker class and get the property in the service class. Refresh the property every 30 seconds.

What would be a clean way of getting the status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two options are really functionally identical.  Both can work just fine for what you need to do.  The second has an implication that the delegate is required, whereas the first implies that it is not.  An event might also imply that it is used beyond the scope of just this one method.

As for the third option, it doesn't give the caller the opportunity to execute code when the number updates, it just gives them the opportunity to access the information.

So if the caller of this type is going to need to do something with this information *every time the value changes) then you should be using something comparable to one of the first two options so that the worker can "push" information to the caller.

If the caller wants to "pull" the information from the worker whenever *it* wants the information, then go with the third option.

Note that there is also a `Progress` class that you can use, with a corresponding `IProgress` interface, that's comparable to your first two options, but is specifically tailored for a worker updating a UI with progress.

Both push and pull methods can actually be sensible for updating a UI with progress of a backround task.  If progress occurs infrequently it may make sense to update the UI every time progress changes, so the UI will want to be "notified" of when those updates happen.  If the updates are very frequent, then the UI may want to instead have a timer and pull the current status every so often, to avoid taxing the UI with more updates than are needed or than it can handle.

Of course, if you're pushing *information* and not just something like a percent complete, then it may be important to not lose any of that information, in which case your 3rd approach isn't an option, as multiple updates may happen in between fetches.

And of course if you're writing a sufficiently generalized worker, you may want to expose *both* a push and pull mechanism, to let the caller choose the appropriate one.